# requestinterstitial one time on click refresh

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to call requestNewInterstitial(); one time only when click refresh_fab not in every click

this is java code

```
 private void showRefreshFab(boolean show) {
    RefreshIcon refreshFAB = (RefreshIcon) findViewById(id.refresh_fab);
    if (show)
        refreshFAB.show();
    else
        refreshFAB.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a flag in your shared preferences to determine if the interstitial has already been shown.

You can make use of [Android-SharedPreferences-Helper](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper) library to simplify your code that deals with the shared preferences.